# Sharp discontinuities in the interpolation and smoothing of closed shapes

Tags: sorting, interpolation, curve-fitting, smoothing, nearest-neighbor

I am working on the edge detection of cells in micro-CT scans. My algorithm does the following: canny edge detection of edges, averages along the edge points, sorting according to polar angle, sort according to nearest neighbor, evenly space out the interpolation values, and finishes by applying a smoothing filter. My goal is to calculate curvature. So far my algorithm is 90% successful, but every once in a while I get unwanted spikes in my resulting shapes. I would greatly appreciate any help.

I've tried the following:

1. Removing any repeating coordinates.
2. Try to remove points that are too far apart from each other.

   Here is an image of the cell shape: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH9jv.png)

   Here is an image of the sorted and evenly interpolated edge points but as you can see there is a huge inverted bump: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOmie.png)

   Here is an image of the smoothed version: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndsDj.png)